# Modifying Google Drive Apps for education platform vs Browser Extension?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-drive-api

I'm working with a few schools to develop a series of interactive textbooks for students. The textbooks need to have randomly generated exercises, for which I've already developed a [prototype](http://mathiom.ozwaldo.net/workbook?mental.2x11.count=10&mental.2x11.min=10&mental.2x11.max=99&mental.3x11.count=10&mental.3x11.min=100&mental.3x11.max=999&mental.pow2_5.count=10&mental.pow2_5.min_10s=1&mental.pow2_5.max_10s=9&mental.2xsum10.count=10&mental.2xsum10.min_1s=1&mental.2xsum10.max_1s=9&mental.2xsum10.min_10s=1&mental.2xsum10.max_10s=9&name=Secrets%20of%20Mental%20Math%3A%20Chapter%200&course=Secrets%20of%20Mental%20Math&course-link=secrets-of-mental-math).

It's also required that the app is managed entirely through Google Drive (eg, I can't use WordPress or even Google Sites), although I can create my own Apps - so long as those can be installed and accessed through Drive.

**What I'd like to do is:**

1. Allow authors to create randomly generated worksheets using Google Forms, similar to how they can with my [current generator](http://mathiom.ozwaldo.net/new-workbook)
2. Allow authors to click on a menu item in Google Docs that embeds a widget/iFrame **inside** a Doc
3. Embed [JSX Graphs](http://jsxgraph.uni-bayreuth.de/wp/) into a Doc
4. Log students answers into a Spreadsheet
5. "Pretty-fy" spreadsheet into a nicer display in an instructors page - either in spreadsheet, doc, or custom Google App
6. Everything must work off of Google Drive

**My questions are:**

1. Is this something that can be achieved purely through Google App Scripts?
2. Would someone *viewing* the Docs be able to see the embedded widgets without my App Scripts installed (if this is even how it works).
3. Can I extend Google Apps (when viewed by a visitor) to show a sidebar with ToC
4. Can cross-document TOC be built, where a TOC is generated from the Headers of all docs in a folder?
5. Would it be easier to create a Browser Extension that can search for certain strings (or even better, a placeholder image with "please install extension") in the app and replace them with the interactive widgets?

**Browser Extension**
Aside from extending Google Apps, I could also create a browser extension that students install that does #2...this would be fairly easy. Of course, "Install" is a scary word for parents, so preferably a solution that doesn't require students to install anything.

I guess, really, my direct question is this: ***Can Google App Scripts alone extend Drive Apps to create interactive textbooks for students and teacher planners.***

Comment: Not to discourage you, but this question is way outside the scope of Q&A in this forum. It's a ["boil the ocean"](http://www.isixsigma.com/public/images_upload/CB-2502_020507--FRM-Boil640.gif) kind of question, notwithstanding the final one-liner. Even for that, the answer would be "Yes - unless you run into something that's impossible." You could try asking narrower questions about specific challenges, keeping within the scope defined in the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented by Mogsdad, your question is indeed overly broad. But I'll attempt to answer it.

From the list you things you'd like, only point 3 may be problematic. You'd have to test if JSX Graphs works well with Apps Script Html Services. I'm afraid it won't. But you have [other Chart](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts/) solutions on Apps Script.

From your list of questions:

1. I don't think so, unless you make some compromises on your requirements.
2. [No, only scripts installed](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2873) on the document/form/spreadsheet itself can embed widgets on it.
3. Not with Apps Script, to run/interact with scripts the user must be a collaborator, not a visitor (meaning he must have edit rights on the file). Maybe with a browser extension.
4. Yes. But if there's "too many" files to be processed, you're likely going to hit some Apps Script quotas that will make your life difficult.
5. I didn't really understood this question. But browser extensions can surely do more than scripts, but they will require installation on each browser for all your users.

Comment: I meant to accept this months ago! I ended up simply asking if they actually really needed those requirements and backed up why it was ridiculously restrictive with your points...and they said no :) Sometimes you just have to ask.